# Get screen remaining width

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I'm trying to create a `HorizontalFieldManager` in blackberry app, I want fields to be left aligned which is HFM's default layout but then I want to display one `BitmapField` right aligned, `setMargin(0, 0, 0, Display.getWidth() - bitmap.getWidth())` works fine until I add other Fields in the manager, any ideas please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a bit hacky, normally the children are the ones who define the alignment inside the parent manager..

You create the hfm using all width available:

```
    HorizontalFieldManager hfm = new HorizontalFieldManager(Field.USE_ALL_WIDTH);
```

Then you add the fields (or managers) aligned to left:

```
    hfm.add(new LabelField("Left", Field.FIELD_LEFT));
```

And then you add the fields that must be aligned right. I'm using labels here, but every class extending Field (including managers) has a constructor accepting flags as argument:

```
    hfm.add(new LabelField("Right", DrawStyle.RIGHT | Field.USE_ALL_WIDTH));
```

Comment: Note that you will have to add this hfm to a VerticalFieldManager (or similar) that is non scrolling horizontally.  Also, not all Fields support Field.USE_ALL_WIDTH, as is required for this to work for the right hand Fields.  Personally I would create a Manager to layout in this way, but since this is the accepted solution, there seems little value in doing that.